# Don't use a jump select on the settings menu in profiles

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, accessibility

Currently, for small screen sizes, the collection of profile links becomes a dropdown:

[image: Dropdown in profile settings]

However, for users using keyboards to navigate, this means a new page is visited every time a new option is selected. This is bad for accessibility, per [WCAG](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#on-input):

> Changing the setting of any user interface component does not automatically cause a change of context unless the user has been advised of the behavior before using the component.

where "change of context" [is](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#dfn-change-of-context):

> Opening a new window, moving focus to a different component, going to a new page (including anything that would look to a user as if they had moved to a new page) or significantly re-arranging the content of a page are examples of changes of context.

So can the menu please be changed, to, say a select and a 'Go' button?

Comment: While I agree this should be improved, a "select and a 'Go' button" is, IMO, a very poor solution. IMO, it's better to handle this with something like: once the navigation input is focused/selected, then keyboard input which would indicate a change of selection causes the popup to open. Then, the user can use the keyboard to navigate around the popup to select the one which they want. Their final selection can be indicated by pressing enter, which will close the popup and navigate to the newly selected page, if the selection is different from the current page.

Answer (score 2):

I second this request in that this navigation should be changed, but I'd say drop the weird choice for a select entirely. I have not been able to get used to this way of navigating the site since it was introduced, which killed my motivation to use the mobile site.

I usually visit "All actions", which on my own profile takes a tap, a long read of 13 options, and another tap to navigate. On other people's profiles, there's 10 options.

This dropdown/select element has two major problems:

### Immersion

It's an (almost) full-screen modal, so it's immersion-breaking. It's like walking through a door into a different room IRL: because the page you were viewing disappears entirely behind the popup menu, your brain is reset.

### Muscle memory

My browser centers it vertically, so based on whose profile I'm viewing (my own or someone else's), the list is either full-screen or slightly less than that.

This breaks muscle memory, so I have to carefully scan and click every time.

So can a UX expert please please please reconsider this UI choice?